# "CP Crash: Don't Power OFF & Contact us" every 2-3 days

Tags: system-error, lg-optimus-l9

Yesterday I unexpectedly got an error message on my 1 week old LG Optimus L9 saying "CP Crash: Don't Power OFF & Contact us" with a timestamp and lost contact with my SIM card.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: Screenshot]

The time displayed in the message was 2 hours ago, the phone was in sleep mode, and I saw the message when I unlocked it.

After restarting the phone, everything went back to normal, and the message has reappeared 7 times since then, even after 2 factory settings resets, LGMobile Support Tool emergency recovery and SIM replacement.

What could cause such error and how can I prevent it in the future?

Android version is 4.1.2 (the latest official update).